# Split, Select, Join in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

What would be the equivalent of the following C# (pseudo) code in PowerShell?

```
string str = "abc def ghi";
str = str.Split(" ").Select(s => "\"" + MakeRootedPath(s) + "\"").Join(" ");
// Result:
str == @"""C:\root\abc"" ""C:\root\def"" ""C:\root\ghi""";
```

It splits the string at spaces, converts each token and puts it into quotes, then recombines the tokens with spaces.

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
$str = $str -Split " " | Select-Object "`"" + (MakeRootedPath $_) + "`"" | -Join " "
```

But that's mostly made up from fragments I found everywhere and I'm pretty sure it won't work like this. I know I could do it the .NET way and write many lines of `[string].Join` and all that, but I'm looking for an elegant PowerShell solution. I know it exists but it's complicated to learn the syntax.

**PS:** Here's the `MakeRootedPath` function for completeness.

```
# Returns a rooted path. Non-rooted paths are interpreted relative to $rootDir.
#
function MakeRootedPath($path)
{
    if (![System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($path))
    {
        return "$rootDir\$path"
    }
    return $path
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a before and after example?

Comment: I've added the output of the C# pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Suppose you have MakeRootedPath somewhere that does something usefull
# I provide a stub here so it is runnable in a console

function MakeRootedpath {"C:\$args"}

# option 1, use foreach-object
('abc def ghi' -split ' ' | foreach-object { "`"$(MakeRootedPath $_ )`""}) -join ' '

# option 2, use select-object (two times, as you need to expand property)
('abc def ghi' -split ' ' | select-object @{N='Item';E={"`"$(MakeRootedPath $_ )`" "}} | 
Select -ExpandProperty Item) -join ' '
```

Answer (score 4):

The `String.Split()` method can be used just like in C#:

```
PS> $str = "abc def ghi"
PS> $str.Split(" ")
abc
def
ghi
```

The `Select()` and `Join()` extension methods are not available but you can use the PowerShell-specific [`ForEach()` method](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/31/powertip-learn-to-use-where-or-foreach-in-powershell-4-0.aspx) and the [`-join` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx):

```
$str.Split(" ").ForEach({"""$(MakeRootedPath $_)"""}) -join " "
```

---

The `ForEach()` extension method is introduced in PowerShell 4.0 - in older version you'll have to use a `foreach(){}` loop:

```
(foreach($s in $str.Split(" ")){"""$(MakeRootedPath $_)"""}) -join " "
```

or pipe to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
($str.Split(" ")|ForEach-Object{"""$(MakeRootedPath $_)"""}) -join " "
```

Comment: Only thing I would consider differently is instead of the `-join` you could just cast as a string.

Comment: @Matt True, but preserving the explicit join separator conveys the intention better than relying on default behavior

Comment: Doesn't work. `ForEach` is not known. Is PowerShell 3.0 too old for this?

Comment: @LonelyPixel Yes, the `ForEach({})` extension method is introduced in PowerShell 4.0

Answer (score 0):

If all your `MakeRootedPath()` does is that it returns an absolute path, use `Join-Path` with appropriate parameters. Like so,

```
$s = "abc def ghi"
$r = "c:\root"
$o = $s -split " " | % { join-path $r $_ }

# Check output for single result
$o[1]
c:\root\def

# Print the whole array
$o
c:\root\abc
c:\root\def
c:\root\ghi
```

As for the added logic, let's use a .Net method to check for absolute path. One could use, say, a regex, to test the input. As there already is a library method, why bother reinventing the wheel?

```
function RootedPath($s, $rootPath) {
    if(-not [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($s)) { 
        return join-path $rootPath $s 
    } else { return $s } 
}
$s = "abc d:\def ghi" # NB: 2nd value is absolute path
$o = $s -split ' ' | % { RootedPath $_ "c:\myRoot" }

# Let's generate a fancy output
$p = '"' + $($o -join '" "') + '"'
$p # print output
"c:\myRoot\abc" "d:\def" "c:\myRoot\ghi"
```

Comment: I've added that function to my question because it's a bit more than that. I use it in my scripts to make it easy to call things.

Comment: Also, the Join is missing in this answer. I need one string as described in the question.